# The set of subfields is totally ordered

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I use Patrice Tauvel Book, i have a problem in the chapter 4 exercice 16: Let $K/k$ extension of field and $\mathcal{F}$ the set of subfeilds. Suppose that for every $M,N \in \mathcal{F}$ we have $M \subset N$ or $N \subset M$. Show that: K is simple extension of $k$ i.e $K=k(x)$ for some $x \in K$.

My idea: is to considere $K$ is Algebraic extension of $k(S)$ (S transendance basis). And we have $card(S) \leq 1$ because for every $x,y$ transcendance we have $k(x) \subset k(y)$ or $k(y) \subset k(x)$. So, if you start like me, i want to prouve K/k(x) is finite extension. Can you help me pleas ?

I dont know if it’s true or not i have a counter example: $k=\Bbb F_p$, the finite field of $p$ elements, and let $K_n=\Bbb F_{p^{2^n}}$,
the finite field of order $p^{2^n}$. The $K_n$ form a chain: $k=K_0\subseteq K_1
\subseteq K_2\subseteq\cdots$. Let $K=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n$. The proper
subfields of $K$ are the $K_n$. These are totally ordered under inclusion.
But $K/k$ is not a simple extension. A simple algebraic extension is finite,
but $K/k$ is infinite algebraic. But i don’t know why the set of subfields of $K$ is exactly {$K_n$}.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41306/when-are-the-intermediate-fields-totally-ordered

Comment: Your counterexample looks fine to me. Don't know what the author had in mind. A simple fix would be to assume that $[K:k]$ is finite, when the chain of intermediate fields must have a maximal intermediate field $M$, and any $x\in K\setminus M$ will do. In that case we don't need to assume separability. This does sound too trivial to be good. If $x\in K\setminus k$ is transcendental, then
neither $k(x^2)$ nor $k(x^3)$ is a subfield of the other, so $K/k$ must be algebraic.